# How do I put a serialized object into a json file with visual basic?

Tags: json, vb.net

I currently have data being pulled from textboxes and comboboxes that are converted into properties of an object, and then that object is seralized into json. I then use the streamwriter function to put that into a json file that has already been created but I just end up with a bunch of weird formatting and things not updating and being added.

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
        Dim monsterName As String
        monsterName = TextBox2.Text
        TextBox2.Text = ""

        Dim monsterCB As Integer
        monsterCB = TextBox3.Text
        TextBox3.Text = ""

        Dim monsterType As String
        monsterType = ComboBox3.SelectedItem
        ComboBox3.Text = ""


        Dim Monster As New Monster

        Monster.MonsterName = monsterName
        Monster.MonsterCombatRating = monsterCB
        Monster.MonsterType = monsterType

        Dim output As String

        output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Monster)

        Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
        file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("C:\Program Files (x86)\D&DLoot\data.json", True)
        file.WriteLine(Monster)
        file.Close()



    End Sub
```

This is within my form code and is the snippet of when my button is clicked for the current form.

Then, in my json file it just writes a new line of

```
WinFormsApp1.Monster
```

So I'm not entirely sure whats going on and what I have missed. I can't see whats wrong with the code above.

Comment: Seems the line `file.WriteLine(Monster)` should instead be `file.WriteLine(output)`.  VB is implicitly using Object.ToString on your `Monster` instance, which is why you see the text you do.

Comment: Ah yeah I see now. Yeah its working how I want it to now at least. Brilliant. Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code in the debugger?  I think it would have been obvious when you reached the `file.WriteLine` step and inspected `Monster` that it wasn't your json.  We all make silly mistakes like this from time to time (at least, I know I do), but they're usually pretty easy to find when you debug.

Comment: Thats a very good point, I'm quite intimidated by the debugging but I should try and use it more and more so that I can self correct like you said

Answer (score 0):

Should be using output in the code below instead of monster. Since the serialized object is in the output, not the monster.

```
    file.WriteLine(Monster)
output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Monster)
```